# Open apple maps on ios 8 and above not working

Tags: ios, apple-maps

Im trying to create an application which will open apple maps located in iOS device with given source and destination address.

```
NSString* addr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=%@&saddr=%@",[_fromTextfield.text stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]],[_toTextfield.text stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]]];

addr=[addr stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];

NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:addr];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]canOpenURL:url])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

But canOpenURL is not working ! It always returns NO.

I have added 
    "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes
    
        urlscheme
        urlscheme2
        urlscheme3
        urlscheme4
    " 
in Info.plist file.

Comment: canOpenURL: failed for URL: "http%3A%2F%2Fmaps.apple.com%2F%3Fdaddr=Liverpool&saddr=Bath" - error: "Invalid input URL"

Comment: I tried your coding.But it shows error.

Comment: If my below answer is helpful for you,please tick and up vote my answer.

Comment: You need to give source and destination.Don't give any percent encoding.You should not give url like that.

Comment: you should pass as query string format in daddr otherwise use pass location coordination

Answer (score 1):

Try below coding.it works perfectly.

```
NSString* addr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=%@&saddr=%@",@"Lacock" ,@"Avebury"];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:addr];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]canOpenURL:url])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If error is 
"This app is not allowed to query for scheme whatsapp"

1) Check Info plist.

```
add LSApplicationQueriesSchemes Array

add whatsapp String.
```

If error is invalid url.

2) Check, whether the string you are passing is not having special characters. Specially whitespace.

```
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
```

then use this string for url.

Both of these should solve. Cheers!